# How to update maximum score in a game?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

In my android game, I want to display max score among all the users. Hence each installation should ping my server to get the maximum value and also update the server if any user scores more than the current maximum. Clearly, these communications with server must be in a separate thread. This can be achieved using `thread` , `AsyncTask` and `service`. 
Game has a no. of `activity`s, some of which may display the maximum score. Hence, it is optimum that the server is pinged as soon as game is started. However, user may move on to next activity very quickly. So, will this destroy the `thread` or `AsyncTask` or `service` ? So, which of the above three methods is more suitable for this requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll want a Singleton class that all of your activities can access. The Singleton can ping your server for the maximum score (I'd recommend using a library like http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) and then keep a reference to it so any activity can access the value.

You can add some more complex methods to the Singleton that handle refreshing from the server and updating the max score if a user beats it. You'll probably want to be able to register a callback with the singleton that will alert an activity if the max score has changed.